# Error after upgrading to ParseSDK 1.7.5 and FacebookSDK 4.4.0 for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

When I try to link a Parse User with Facebook using PFFacebookUtilsV4, it is giving me the following alert:

"Please log into this app again to reconnect your Facebook account"

Here is the block of code where I call PFFacebookUtils:

```
/**
 * Import people you are friends with on facebook from the database
 */
- (void)beginImportingFacebookFriendsForUserWithBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *results, NSError *error))cb {

  if (![PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]]) {

    NSArray *permissionsArray = @[@"user_about_me", @"user_friends", @"user_events"];
    [PFFacebookUtils linkUserInBackground:[PFUser currentUser] withReadPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
      if (succeeded) {
        FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                                                       parameters:nil];
        [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
          if (!error) {
            NSString *fbId = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
            NSMutableDictionary *currentUserDict = [[prefs objectForKey:@"currentUser"]mutableCopy];
            NSLog(@"currentUserDict:%@",currentUserDict);
            [currentUserDict setObject:fbId forKey:@"fbId"];
            [prefs setObject:currentUserDict forKey:@"currentUser"];
            [prefs setObject:fbId forKey:@"currentFbId"];
            [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:fbId forKey:@"fbId"];
            [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];

            [self finishImportingFacebookFriendsForUserWithBlock:cb];
          }
        }];
      }
    }];
  }
  else {
    [self finishImportingFacebookFriendsForUserWithBlock:cb];
  }
}

- (void)finishImportingFacebookFriendsForUserWithBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))cb {
  FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                                                 parameters:nil];
  [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
      if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"result objectforkey:data %@", [result objectForKey:@"data"]);
        cb([result objectForKey:@"data"], error);
      }
      else NSLog(@"error!:%@",error);
    });
  }];
}
```

Here is what I'm getting in the console log:

```
2015-08-05 21:18:54.723 Huddlr[2965:391917] error!:Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 8.)" UserInfo=0x1741aca20 {NSRecoveryAttempter=<_FBSDKLoginRecoveryAttempter: 0x174019da0>, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please log into this app again to reconnect your Facebook account., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=190, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=400, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=2, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorSubcode=460, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 190;
            "error_subcode" = 460;
            message = "Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}, NSLocalizedRecoveryOptions=(
    OK,
    Cancel
)}
```

The error message is "Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password." even though the password has not been changed. If anyone knows what is going on here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: we are seeing this now in our app also, only for some users.  Looking on how to resolve it, since we can't reproduce it on any company devices/accounts.

Comment: Any updates on this? Also having this issue

Comment: the issue was that some of the old accounts were still linked to facebook, and so in the above code we were trying to link them a second time. We fixed the issue by first making sure all accounts were unlinked, then linking them again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting Error validating access token -code 460- then you should logout user and call login.